# Stop vscode from translating warnings/errors

Tags: c#, locale, visual-studio-code

I've setup vscode to use English language, but the warning and error snippets keep being translated to my locale language. How can I stop vscode from doing that, since googling possible warnings/errors is much easier with them in English?

I have already tried changing the Locale settings within vscode, and already changed them to English. But the snippets keep being translated.

Comment: Have tried setting your OS language to English?

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and this resolved my issue.

Press F1 or CTRL + SHIFT + P and type "Configure Display Language", then pick "en".

More info: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/locales